# The href showing when right clicking and trying to print a web page

Tags: html, asp.net, printing

I have not seen this before, so i am not sure how to fix it, this is a asp.net project and on the clients website. When he is Right clicking and chosing print in a browser, the print page shows all the hrefs from the links, and not just the text or picture that i wold like.

Anyone knows what i have done wrong here.

[image: print page and orginal website]

update based on the awnser under.

if i remove the @media print tag in bootstrap.css it works fine.

Comment: Its better if you show the code, and the css for the links, or else you count on the experience of the users here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some accessibility [`@media print` stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773044/css-print-style-sheets-examples) applied which contains something like:

```
a:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
```

See [CSS print preview - show image/link URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248653/css-print-preview-show-image-link-urls).